# Connecting my login application from android(ADT) to ms sql server 2008

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I'm pretty new on java and android programming. I'm trying to connect an android application to a SQL Server database installed on a Windows laptop.
I'm programming under Windows using ADT.I added the jtds-1.2.5.jar too
The code is the following (placed in the MainActivity.java):

```
          package com.test;
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.AsyncTask;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.ProgressBar;
     import android.widget.TextView;
     import android.widget.Toast;
     import java.sql.Connection;
     import java.sql.ResultSet;
     import java.sql.Statement;
       public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       ConnectionClass connectionClass;
       EditText e1, e2;
       Button btnlogin;
       TextView t1, t2;
       ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DoLogin doLogin = new DoLogin();
            doLogin.execute("");

        }
    });

}

public class DoLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;

    String userid = e1.getText().toString();
    String password = e2.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (isSuccess) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successfull",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (userid.trim().equals("") || password.trim().equals(""))
            z = "Please enter User Id and Password";
        else {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    z = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {
                    String query = "select * from LoginTable where username='"
                            + userid + "' and password='" + password + "'";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                    if (rs.next()) {

                        z = "Login successfull";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    } else {
                        z = "Invalid Credentials";
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = "Exceptions";
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
   }
 }
```

When I press the "connect to database" button I receive the following error message:
Can someone help me with this?

```
     09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     09-05 
     11:32:42.505:E/AndroidRuntime(1402):java.lang.NullPointerException
     09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):    at 
     com.test.MainActivity$DoLogin.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:54)
     09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):    at 
      android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
     09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):    at 
    android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
   09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):  at 
      com.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
      09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):   at 
    android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
     09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):    at 
       android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
      09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):   at 
        android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
       09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):  at 
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):     at 
        android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):     at 
            android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):     at 
              java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
               09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):  at 
              java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
             09-05 11:32:42.505: 
            E/AndroidRuntime(1402):atcom.android.internal.os
           .ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller
                       .run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                     09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):    at 
             com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                        09-05 11:32:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(1402):     at 
                       dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                      09-05 11:32:46.115: I/Process(1402): Sending signal. 
                         PID: 1402 SIG: 9
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

In `DoLogin` class

```
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

here you getting null pointer exception because you doesn't define `progressBar` in the scope.